# How to decode "\320\240\321\203" with PHP

Tags: php, encoding

I have this string: **\320\260\320\275\320\264\320\260**

I know it is cyrillic (value from a database), but I need to translate this to the correct UTF-8 String. Is there a php function to handle this or do I have to write my own?

Comment: Where does that string come from and what kind of encoding does it represent?

Comment: Oracle Database Export, think it represents utf8?

Comment: Is this a 8 byte string or a 32 byte string of digits and \ escapes?  if the former, then is is already in utf-8.  You just need to display it using a UTF-8 character set or convert it to the appropriate single byte charset.  If the latter why not validate and pack?

Comment: PHP functions to change encodings exists a lot of. The question is more which encoding this is you ask about. Is that data in the database or is it "from" the database and in PHP (e.g. inside a PHP variable)?

Comment: it is stored in an database, i cant check how it is stored (-:

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this an 8-octet string, composed of the characters \320, \260, \320, etcetera? If so, it's already UTF-8 and you don't have to do anything:

```
echo "\320\260\320\275\320\264\320\260";
// Output: анда
```

If it's a 32-octet string instead, composed of the characters \, 3, 2, 0, etc, it needs some processing:

```
// helper function to convert octal numbers to characters
function oct2chr($x) {return chr(octdec($x));}

$input = "\\320\\260\\320\\275\\320\\264\\320\\260";
$output = preg_replace('/\\\\[0-7]{3}/e', 'oct2chr("$0")', $input);
// alternative: implode("", array_map("oct2chr", explode("\\", $input)));
echo $output;
// Output: анда
```